# Hasse-Minkowski for cubic forms

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, p-adic-number-theory

We know that an analogue of the Hasse-Minkowski theorem does not hold for all cubic forms, e.g. because Selmer's cubic:
$$
3x^3 + 4y^3 + 5z^3 = 0
$$
has solutions over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for all $p$, but no solutions over $\mathbb{Q}$.

My questions are:

1. Can we find a (non-trivial) class of cubic forms where an analogue of the Hasse-Minkowski theorem does hold?
2. Is there any intuition for *why* the local-global principle holds for quadratic but fails for cubic forms?
3. Are there higher degree forms where the local-global principle holds again?
4. Are questions like these addressed anywhere in the literature?

Many thanks.

Comment: Many things that holds in the quadratic case can break down in higher degrees: all quadratic forms (in characteristic zero, say) can be diagonalized, every quadratic extension of $\mathbf Q$ is a Galois extension, the splitting of primes in a quadratic extension can be described in terms of arithmetic progressions, the ring of integers of every quadratic field has the form $\mathbf Z[\alpha]$, the different ideal of every quadratic field is principal, and so on. (Some of those properties are related.) In degrees above two there is "more room" for new phenomena to happen.

Comment: A setting in higher degrees where there is a local-global principle is central simple algebras (including, but not limited to, quaternion algebras). That is the Albert–Brauer–Hasse–Noether theorem mentioned on the Wikipedia page for the Hasse principle.

Comment: @KCd That does provide some intuition! Quadratic fields certainly do have some nice properties that aren't true in general, but if we take the example you mentioned of e.g. cubic extensions over $\mathbb{Q}$ not all being Galois, my point is that if we adjoin a primitive root of unity to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, the extension becomes Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ - this might be interpreted as intuitively equivalent to having some restrictions on the cubic forms or moving to higher degree forms for the Hasse principle to apply. - Speaking very roughly, that is.

Comment: I think Bhargava et al have written about the statistics of failure for... ternary cubics and Thue equations https://arxiv.org/search/advanced?advanced=1&terms-0-operator=AND&terms-0-term=bhargava&terms-0-field=author&terms-1-operator=AND&terms-1-term=hasse&terms-1-field=title&classification-physics_archives=all&classification-include_cross_list=include&date-filter_by=all_dates&date-year=&date-from_date=&date-to_date=&date-date_type=submitted_date&abstracts=show&size=50&order=-announced_date_first

Comment: @yoyo Thanks! I knew about Bhargava's work on e.g. the statistical density of elliptic curves satisfying the BSD conjecture, but I did not know about this work on cubics that satisfy the Hasse principle - and they even restrict themselves to *plane* cubics - that is very interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Let $L/\mathbb{Q}$ a Galois cyclic extension of degree $3$. Then the norm form $N:x\in L\mapsto N_{L/\mathbb{Q}}(x))$ is a cubic form in the coordinates of $x$ in a fixed basis of $L$. Now fix $a\in\mathbb{Q}$

By a theorem of Hilbert,  Hasse principle holds for the affine cubic form $x\mapsto N(x)-a$ ( a rational number is globally a norm of a cyclic extension if and only if it is locally)

Note this is true if you replace $3$ by any integer, provided you restrict yourself to cyclic extensions. You can also replace $\mathbb{Q}$ ny a global field.

2. I don't know if the following will give you "intuition", but certainly it will explain a lot (but not all) counter examples to Hasse principle. The keywords are: Brauer-Manin obstruction, and you can find a lot of things about it in the literature.
   This is an obstruction coming from Brauer-Hasse-Noether theorem for central simple algebras.

You can find a nice introduction to the definition here: http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/S.Siksek/arith/notes/brauermanin.pdf

3. I don't think so. Using Brauer-Manin obstruction, you can construct counterexamples of any prescribed degree.

For example, Bayer, Lee and Parimala computed the Brauer Manin obstruction for multinorm equations, and I'm pretty sure that we can use their work to construct counterexamples of arbitrary large degree. The full paper is available on Parimala's web page.

Comment: Oh very good! I am very happy with your answers to (2) and (3), and (1) is absolutely wonderful, but in relation to this, I have two further questions: (i) Does that constitute the class of *all* cubic forms that satisfy the local-global principle? (ii) Do you know where I could find a proof of the statement?

Comment: For (1), Idon't think so: take the equation $xyz=0$, for example. This obviously satisfies Hasse principle, but $xyz$ is not the norm form of any field extension (because the only zero of a norm form is 0). For Hasse thm, this is part of class field theory, and you can find a proof in any  sufficiently textbook on the subject. I'm pretty sure you can find a reference too in the Bayer-Lee-Parimala's paper I mentioned.

Comment: Great! And one last question: Does the Brauer-Manin obstruction give us an if and only if condition for a curve to satisfy the local-global principle? I.e. does the set of all curves that satisfy the conditions of the Brauer-Manin obstruction constitute the set of *all* curves for which the local-global principle does not apply?

Comment: I have found that the Manin obstruction does not give an if and only if condition, as you indeed alluded to in your post. So my follow-up question is: What might go wrong in the cases where the Manin obstruction does not say anything?

Comment: This is an active field of research and i'm not an expert. You've refined Brauer-Manin obstructions, but they do not explain all the counter examples. Poonen constructed examples of varieties failing to satisfy Hasse principle , and which cannot be explained by the refined Brauer Manin obstructions. If you want to know more on the subject, you should read the work of Colliot-Thélène, Demarche, Poonen...